# Expression must have class type error

Tags: c

I'm working on a homework assignment and I've hit a brick wall. I think I have all of the code that I need, I just need to get the program to compile. The object of the assignment is

Create a structure to hold student names and averages.  The structure should contain a first name, last name and an integer grade average.

Then:

Write a program that will do the following:

> > 1.) Create an array of pointers to these student structures.
> >
> > 2.) Prompt the user for names and averages.
> >
> > 3.) After you get the student’s information use malloc to provide the memory to store the information.
> >
> > 4.) Place the address of the student, returned by malloc, into the pointer array.
> >
> > 5.) AFTER the user indicates there are no more students:
>
> Search the data entered and find the highest and lowest grade
>   average.
>
> a)Print the name and grade for the highest grade
>
> b)Print the name and grade for the lowest grade
>
> c)Print the average of all grades entered

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define SIZE 25


int enterStudents (int ePointArray[SIZE]);
void searchData (int *sPointArray, int *sHigh, int *sLow);
int calculateAvg (int, int *avgPointArray);
void printData (int, int *pHigh, int *pLow);


struct student
{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int average;
};


int main()
{
    int pointArray[SIZE], high[3], low[3];
    int i = 0, studentCounter, avgGrade; 


    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        pointArray[i] = 0;


    studentCounter = enterStudents(pointArray);


    searchData(pointArray, high, low);


    avgGrade = calculateAvg(studentCounter, pointArray);


    printData(avgGrade, high, low);




    return 0;
}




int enterStudents (int ePointArray[SIZE])
{
    char tempFname[20], tempLname[20], yesNo[2] = "y";
    int tempAvg, counter = 0;
    int *studPtr;

    struct student aStud={"\0", "\0", 0};




    while( counter < SIZE && strcmp(yesNo, "y")==0)
    {
        printf(" Enter first name: ");
        scanf("%s", tempFname);


        printf(" Enter last name: ");
        scanf("%s", tempLname);


        printf(" Enter grade average:");
        scanf("%d", tempAvg);


        strcpy(aStud.firstName, tempFname);
        strcpy(aStud.lastName, tempLname);
        aStud.average = tempAvg;


        studPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct student));


        ePointArray[counter] = *studPtr;


        counter++;


        printf("/n");
        printf(" Do you have more students? yes or no:");
        scanf("%s", yesNo);
    }


    return counter;


}

void searchData (int sPointArray[SIZE], int sHigh[3], int sLow[3])
{
    int searchCounter = 0;


    while( searchCounter = 0)
    {
        if( *sPointArray[searchCounter].average > *sPointArray[searchCounter+1].average)
        {
            sHigh[0] = &sPointArray[searchCounter].firstName;
            sHigh[1] = &sPointArray[searchCounter].lastName;
            sHigh[2] = &sPointArray[searchCounter].average;
        }

        if( *sPointArray[searchCounter].average < *sPointArray[searchCounter+1].average)
        {
            sLow[0] = &sPointArray[searchCounter].firstName;
            sLow[1] = &sPointArray[searchCounter].lastName;
            sLow[3] = &sPointArray[searchCounter].average;
        }


        searchCounter++;
    }


}


int calculateAvg( int totalStudents, int avgPointArray[SIZE])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int avgCounter;
    double overallAvg;


    for( avgCounter = 0; avgCounter < totalStudents; avgCounter++)
        sum = sum + *avgPointArray[avgCounter].average;


    overallAvg = sum/totalStudents;


    return overallAvg;
}




void printData (int pAverage, int pHigh[3], int pLow[3])
{
    printf(" Highest Grade: %s %s %d", pHigh[0], pHigh[1], pHigh[3]);
    printf("/n");
    printf(" Lowest Grade: %s %s %d", pLow[0], pLow[2], pLow[3]);
    printf("/n");
    printf(" Average Grade: %d",pAverage);


}
```

The main chunk of problems come from the searchData function. In the if statements, every occurrence of *sPointArray and &sPointArray is underlined in red and the error reads

```
 "Error: expression must have class type"
```

The same thing also happens in the calculateAvg function with *avgPointArray in the for loop. I know that the error is a fairly common problem for noobie C programmers (i.e myself) and that it generally has to do with writing the code as a function instead of a statement or something like that, but I can't for the life of me find where I have went wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated. I've been working at this for so long my vision is blurring.

Also, for anyone who solves this in like two seconds and wants proof that I'm a true idiot, there is an error in the enterStudents function where it says StudPtr = malloc(sizeof...). The error shows under the assignment symbol and says

`"Error: a value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int*".`

I understand this concept in theory, but some advice for how to fix it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: To start with, your loop `while( searchCounter = 0)` will _never_ run.

Comment: It'll run once won't it? Since searchCounter is initialized as 0 at first?

Comment: Remember that in C zero is considered false, so as you assign zero to `searchCounter` the whole expression will be zero so the expression is false and wont enter the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You declare the `sPointArray` as an array of integers, but use it as an array of structures.

Comment: I do? Hm... I understand how I declared it as an array of integers, but what do you mean I'm using it as an array of structures? How would I even start going about correcting that?

Comment: @Vyreinos For example `sPointArray[searchCounter].average`. The `.` is used to access structure members, and can't be used on types other than structures (like an `int`). I think you really want e.g. `struct student sPointArray[SIZE]`. You should also read more about pointers, dynamic memory allocations, and what the dereference operator `*` and address of operator `&` does. You have many more (and much more serious) problems in your code than these "simple" syntax errors.

Comment: Hm, alright. I'll play around with it and see what I can do. Thanks for your help. I'll read up on it like you suggested and see what I find. I guess if worst comes to worst my teacher will just call me an idiot again =P Really though, thanks. I appreciate it.